# call external C library from COBOL

Tags: c, linker, cobol

I'm extperimenting COBOL last times and I having trouble with link and external call with COBOL

First, i have a simple test lib source code:

```c
// testlib.c
#include <stdio.h>

void CFUNC() {
    printf("This is a C function.\n");
}
```

I compile my lib with theres:
`gcc -c -o testlib.o testlib.c` and after `ar rcs libout.a testlib.o`

I have a cobol source file:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. CallCFunction.


PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    EXTERNAL "CFUNC".
    CALL "CFUNC"
    STOP RUN.
```

I compile this with `cobc -x -free -o cobollink cobollink.cbl -L/path/to/lib -lout`

I'm having this error:

```
cobollink.cbl:6: error: syntax error, unexpected EXTERNAL
```

The "EXTERNAL" should not be here ? The code compile well without EXTERNAL but CFUNC is not found

How can I call my C function ?

```bash
$cobc -V
cobc (GnuCOBOL) 4.0-early-dev.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Keisuke Nishida, Roger While, Ron Norman, Simon Sobisch, Edward Hart
Built     Sep 14 2021 19:23:38
Packaged  Jun 06 2020 20:56:36 UTC
C version "11.2.0"
```

(using UBUNTU 22.04)

Thanks

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes typo sry, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get it working via the following:

- Same CFUNC file contents

Couple changes:

- Compiled with `gcc -c CFUNC.c -o CFUNC.o` (not as static lib, if you need it static I can look into that, just going off of what I found quickly researching)
- New test.cbl (just remove `EXTERNAL` keyword):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. CallCFunction.


PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    CALL "CFUNC"
    STOP RUN.
```

- Compile that with `cobc -x -free -o cobollink test.cbl CFUNC.o` (assuming CFUNC.o and COBOL source are in same folder)

Output:

```
<path...>/Experiments/COBOL/c_from_cobol$ ./cobollink 
This is a C function.
```

Comment: Note: the linker _may_ see an unused `CFUNC` because this is resolved at runtime only - either add `-static` (to use static calls for all literal) or  `-K CFUNC` (to only do so for this) - or change the code to read `CALL STATIC "CFUNC"`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in trying [gcobol](https://cobolworx.com/pages/cobforgcc.html), a new COBOL compiler based on gcc.  Under development for 18 months, and still going strong.

```
$ gcc -c -o test.o  test.c
$ gcobol -oo test.cbl test.o
$ ./o
This is a C function.
$
```

In gcobol, the CALL target by default is converted to lowercase to make it case-insensitive, consistent with the ISO standard.  To make your example work, either the C function must be lowercase, or you use the CDF CALL-CONVENTION statement to invoke the target verbatim.